# Sending a Matlab Image to an Android tablet

Tags: java, android, matlab, bluetooth, javax.imageio

I have developed an Android app that connects with a laptop running Matlab over Bluetooth SPP.  I am able to send strings back and forth easily and I am now interested in sending an image from Matlab to display on tablet (48x64 grayscale would be sufficient).  I am unsure how to package an image and send it over at Matlab serial port. I am guessing you cannot just use fprintf or fwrite.

This is what I think the Android side might look like

```
public void drawImage(byte[] buffer){
    ImageView camView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camView);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length);  
    Log.d(TAG,"decoded image");
    if(myBitmap != null){
    camView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    Log.d(TAG,"Trying to display...");
    }
    else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap = null");
    }
}// end drawImage
```

Any advice on either the Andriod or Matlab side would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working.  Basically the issue was that I was not sending the image with the proper compression (either .jpg or .png).  I found that if you have a Matlab image which Matlab represents simply as a matrix of pixel values regardless of compression you need to create a java BufferedImage in order to properly construct the byte array so you can decode it on the Android side.

The Matlab side

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
serCam = InitUSBcamera;  % initialize USB camera as a serial port
type = java.lang.String('jpg'); % translating matlab to java 
outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream; % create java output stream
im = getsnapshot(serCam);  % get an image from the camera
im2 = imresize(im, [96,128],'nearest');  % reduce the size 
im3 = im2java2d(im2); % create java Buffered Image
ImageIO.write(im3, type, outputStream);
bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
fwrite(serTablet, bytes, 'int8') % send the image // changed to async
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to receive serial data from Matlab? Why not treat it like any other serial data.

I would debug through an Android console application first to make sure it’s transmitting at all, and also to be sure that the data is transmitting the way you want it to transmit.